# RegEx with | (or) in it

Tags: regex

I have a long RegEx that is working, but I have a section at the end that is perplexing me. I have a scenario where I am parsing some HTML and one of two scenarios can happen.  Either the pattern I am searching for ends with a X followed immediately by a single digit or it's a `&nbsp;`.  Here's the RegEx fragment:

```
(X(\d+)|&nbsp;)
```

As you might have noticed, I don't care about the X or the `&nbsp;`, I just want to capture the digit if it's there.  It appears that in order to use the |, I have to use a capture group.  So now I get BOTH X5 AND 5 if that pattern exists.  I really just want the digit captured if it's there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the effect of grouping, without the effect of capturing, use the `(?:...)` notation:

```
(?:X(\d+)|&nbsp;)
```

This is equivalent to what you wrote, except that it doesn't create a capture group for `X5`, only for `5`.

(By the way, you say "a single digit", but your regex has `\d+` rather than `\d`, so it can actually match *multiple* digits.)

Comment: The \d+ was intentional.  I was simply making sure that if the pattern suddenly had more than one digit, I was covered.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a non-capturing group?

```
(?:X(\d+)|&nbsp;)
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
(?:X(\d+)|&nbsp;)
```

adding `?:` you actually disable the backreference while grouping.

Answer (score 2):

Use a non-capturing group:

```
(?:X(\d+)|&nbsp;)
```